# gcc is not found(In fact gcc5.4 have been installed) when installing juliapro 0.6.1.1 on Ubuntu16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, julia

I would like to install Juliapro 0.6.1 on Ubuntu 16.04, I download juliapro, and according to the official guideline,

1.

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install gcc
sudo apt-get -y install python2.7-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libzmq5
sudo apt-get -y install hdf5-tools`

```
sudo apt-get -y install default-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64
```

2.

`~ ./install_juliapro.sh JuliaPro-0.6.1.1_build-179.tgz  ~/juliapro`

3 While it shows:

```
 OS Detected: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
 Online Installation : Requires internet access Like: Ubuntu
 Checking pre-requisites

 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

 gcc is not installed. Please install gcc first !
 Installation terminated as dependencies are not met.
```

4 In fact, I have installed gcc, and I type

`gcc`,

it returns:

`/usr/bin/gcc`

I couldn't solve this, and I don't know why. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: 5 years ago I installed julia from source and it was painless ... I too am encountering all manor of errors attempting to install on Ubuntu 16.04 however I then tried and succeeded getting julia up and running using their docker container ... `docker run -it juliacomputing/juliapro:latest 
` ... which is a 2 gig monster so I suggest running it from your handy cloud VPS and not on your laptop ... if my life depended on it my next step would be to execute locally what they have working in their Dockerfile  ...  https://juliacomputing.com/blog/2017/11/29/juliapro-ami-and-docker-image.html

Comment: Thanks. I know a little about Docker, now I'm searching it. It's wonderful, while I still like to fix the above problem.